# Python: how to retrieve some values from the elements of a list?

Tags: python, list, extract

I have a list of elements like this:

`mylist=['event_100of1000', 'event_17of1000', 'event_1000of1000',...]`

How can I extract the "number" of the event only and produce another list, in the likes of:

`extracted_list=['100','17','1000',...]`?

Comment: `split()` should help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `lstrip` for your `event_` and then `split` for `'of'`:

```
res = [i.lstrip('event_').split('of')[0] for i in mylist]

print(res)
['100', '17', '1000']
```

**EDIT**

```
res = [int(i.lstrip('event_').split('of')[0]) for i in mylist]

print(res)
[100, 17, 1000]
```

Comment: Ok, I guess the elements in the list are strings. Could I turn them into `int`?

Comment: use `int()` wrapper?

Comment: Like `print(int(res))`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'regex' for this....

```
>>> import re
>>> mylist=['event_100of1000', 'event_17of1000', 'event_1000of1000']
>>> [re.findall('_(\d+)', i)[0] for i in mylist]

['100', '17', '1000']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use map:

```
  events = map(lambda x: x.split('of')[0], mylist)
  map(lambda x: x.split('_')[1], events)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension and regular expressions:

```
import re
mylist=['event_100of1000', 'event_17of1000', 'event_1000of1000',...]
extracted_list = [re.search("\d+", x).group(0) for x in mylist]
```

Answer (score 1):

I also would use re

```
import re
mylist=['event_100of1000', 'event_17of1000', 'event_1000of1000']
list_id_of = [re.search("event_(\d+)of(\d+)", e).groups() for e in mylist]

[('100', '1000'), ('17', '1000'), ('1000', '1000')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use re

```
import re
mylist=['event_100of1000', 'event_17of1000', 'event_1000of1000']
pattern = re.compile(r'^event_(\d+).')

mylist = list(map(lambda x : pattern.findall(x)[0] , mylist))
print(mylist)
#['100', '17', '1000']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` function for this:

```
>>> extracted_list = map(lambda x: int(x[:x.find('of')].lstrip('event_')), mylist)
>>> print extracted_list
[100, 17, 1000]
```